# VB6 designer doesn't display opened modules

Tags: vb6, ide, designer

Forms and Modules in VB6 don't show when I double click them. In order to have them appear on screen I have to click Window > Cascade and everything moves into place, but when I open them from the project view nothing appears.

It seems like designer windows are displayed out of view... how can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The form windows positioning, and which forms are open, is stored in the `ProjectName.vbw` file.  Delete that file then open your project and the previous form windows settings are forgotten.  The `.vbw` file should not be added to your source control system, there's nothing in it that is needed for code history reasons.

Comment: I deleted the file as you suggested, and it didn't help. I think it has something to do with multiple display support, since right clicks drop the menu in a different screen.

Comment: @HéctorÁlvarez you accepted this as the answer, but your last comment seemed to disagree with it. Can you clarify?

Comment: I added that fact to your answer as clarification, but it's been either revoked or still pending for approval. Either way, the answer works as long as you combine both your answer and my additional comment, i.e. you need to remove the `.vbw` file and then make sure the IDE runs in the main display, otherwise you still get windows out of range.